# Ajuda com php e json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou com dificuldade em exibir corretamente em `JSON`, um resultado originado de duas tabelas do meu banco de dados.

A situação é a seguinte: tenho pedidos em uma tabela (A) e os produtos desse pedido em outra tabela (B).

O resultado JSON que possuo é como esse:

```
{
    "pedidos": [
            {
              "numOrc": "1",
              "nomeclie": "CONSUMIDOR",
              "valortotal": "2.077,20",
              "formapagto": "2",
              "emissao": "2013-02-15 16:09:11",
              "codprod": "4775",
              "qtdade": "1",
              "valorunit": "500,00",
              "tipopreco": "B"
             },
             {
              "numOrc": "2",
              "nomeclie": "MARCELO AUGUSTO BOTURA",
              "valortotal": "2.077,20",
              "formapagto": "2",
              "emissao": "2013-02-15 16:21:56",
              "codprod": "4775",
              "qtdade": "1",
              "valorunit": "500,00",
              "tipopreco": "B"
             }
            ]
}
```

Como dá pra perceber, o resultado que eu tenho é só de um produto em cada pedido. Eu precisava que o resultado fosse como abaixo (Atenção para "tag `Detalhes`"):

```
{
    "pedidos": [
             {
              "numOrc": "2",
              "nomeclie": "MARCELO AUGUSTO BOTURA",
              "valortotal": "2.077,20",
              "formapagto": "2",
              "emissao": "2013-02-15 16:21:56",
              "Detalhes": 
               [
                {
                 "codprod": "4775",
                 "qtdade": "1",
                 "valorunit": "500,00",
                 "tipopreco": "B"
                },
                {
                 "codprod": "5555",
                 "qtdade": "3",
                 "valorunit": "800,00",
                 "tipopreco": "A"
                }
               ]
             }
            ]
}
```

Meu código PHP está assim:

```
$sqlcode2 = mysql_query("Select a.numero as numOrc, a.nomeclie, a.valortotal, a.formapagto, a.emissao, b.codprod, b.qtdade, b.valorunit, b.tipopreco from orcamento a, prodorc b");


$jsonObj= array();


if($something == 'all')
 {  
   while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode2))
  {
   $jsonObj[] = $result;
   $teste= array('pedidos' => $jsonObj);
  }
 }

$final_res =json_encode($teste);
echo $final_res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, dependendo da estrutura de suas tabelas você pode fazer um join na tabela de produtos usando a tabela de orçamento, se na tabela de orçamento guardar apenas os cabeçalhos do orçamento e tiver os produtos lançados nos orçamentos separados em outra tabela, você poderá usar a dica de cima, se não, se não existir separação de cabeçalho e produtos, você terá de no método que faz a montagem do `JSON` ler o cabeçalho do orçamento recuperado na consulta e em um loop verificar se o registro onde o cursor está corresponde àquele orçamento capturado, se corresponder você terá de adicionar um objeto ao `JSON` do orçamento com as informações do produto.

Comment: A mesma que comecei, no caso é ao que me refiro no começo da resposta, desculpa realmente eu li aqui e ficou um pouco vago mesmo. Mas eu me refiro ao começo quando digo "se na tabela de orçamento guardar apenas os cabeçalhos..."

Comment: Logo que escrevi, eu entendi a que se referia rs. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, até eu depois que você falou não entendi bem o que eu escrevi, mas é assim vivendo e aprendendo. Espero ter ajudado. Bom dia

Comment: Eu fiz o INNER JOIN, agora o resultado me mostra todos os produtos, mas não no formato que eu precisava... Agora fica "repetindo o cabeçalho" do dorçamento, toda a vez que tem um produto... Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Grande, no caso o que você pode fazer é:

fazer um loop nos resultados que foram coletados montado o JSON do cabeçalho e depois adicionar os produtos, seria mais ou menos assim

Orçamento 1:
Cabeçalho : id = 1
                    cliente = 1
                   valor = 10,00

produtos: id = 1
                valor = 5,00

                id = 2
              valor = 5,00

no caso como o cabeçalho de repete você teria que montar o loop verificando se cada registro pertence ao cabeçalho do registro anterior, se pertencer você lança o produto no mesmo cabeçalho como um novo objeto JSON